# Limit Geocode results based on application extent?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

I am creating an Esri Flex API application (not the viewer), and have been creating a tool to use the [World Places Locator](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=991a730ac41248428b48584ccf77b583).

For now, I am just zooming to the top scoring candidate returned.

If you [search for Brighton](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/ESRI_Places_World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?PlaceName=&SingleLine=brighton&outFields=city%2Cstate%2Ccountry%2CWest_Lon%2CEast_Lon%2CNorth_Lat%2CSouth_Lat&outSR=&f=html), it returns you 20 candidates, sorted by score.

I read on an older blog post:

> You can also filter the results by extent using client logic. The
>   candidates field to look for in this case are North_Lat, South_Lat,
>   East_Lon, and West_Lon.  [Source](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/arcgisonline/archive/2009/10/22/world-places-locator.aspx).

I am thinking it would be a good idea to have a tickbox on my search, that limits the results to the current extent of the map in the Flex app.  (Or maybe buffer a litte out from the view).

I understand the logic on how to go about this, but was wondering if anyone has already done this (does not have to be Flex) so that I can save some time coding it.

If not, I will have a go at this next weekend and post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar using C# and LINQ.  Basically, I just get the extent from the map, then using LINQ, I queried for the X and Y values that fall within the extent.  A crude way to do it would be with if statements.  I just googled and found this implementation of linq for ActionScript called ActionLinq:

http://www.srtsolutions.com/introducing%E2%80%A6-actionlinq

So here is some pseudo code without using Linq:

```
candidatesInExtent = new List;

foreach (candidate in returnedCandidates)
  if(candidate.x > extent.minX || candidate.y > extent.minY)
    if(candidate.x < extent.maxX || candidate.y < extent.maxY)
        candidatesInExtent.add(candidate);
```